# Regularity for transport equation?

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations

In the book of Evans the transport equation,
$$\frac{d}{dt} u + b\cdot \nabla u = 0, \quad u(t=0)=u_0,$$
is solved by the method of charateristics for $b$ and $u_0$ smooth enogh (in terms of $\mathcal{C}^k$ for some $k$).

I am not an expert for hyperbolic equations and I see this equation as a prototyp of hyperbolic equations of first order and I thought that there are some results of this equation in Sobolev spaces. But I haven't found some (expect for strong solutions or the result of DiPerna and Lions; see below).

To be more precise: I wonder if there is any result of the type: If $b$ and $u_0$ are contained in some Sobolev spaces, then $u\in L^p(W^{k,q})=L^p(0,T;W^{k,p})$ for $k\geq 1$ and some $p,q$? I know the paper of DiPerna and Lions from 1989, where develop a theory of this equation in Sobolev spaces, but they don't study if the solution $u$ has a (weak) derivative (or even more).

Does anyone knows an article for this equation or (if not) a good reference (book or survey article) for beginners in hyperbolic equations?

Thanks a lot!

Edit: 1) $b$ can be assumed as divergence free, $\nabla \cdot b=0$.
2) Higher regularity (in terms of derivates for $u$) can be established by the method, Willi Wong mentioned in his comment. This question is okay now. Does anyone has a reference for a beginng guide for hyperbolic equations or a survey article with further archiements than DiPerna and Lions?

Comment: By $L^p(W^{k,q})$ do you mean $L^p$ in time and $W^{k,q}$ in space? In general unless you localize in time you certainly cannot get something that strong, just by using regularity of $b$. You will also need algebraic structure. For example, in the case where $\nabla\cdot b = 0$, you have that the transport equation _conserves every spatial $L^q$ norm_, which means that it cannot have the decay in time necessary for $L^p$ in time except with $p = \infty$. 

Comment: @Willie Wong: Yes, I mean $L^p(W^{k,p}):=L^p(0,T;W^{k,p})$ for a bounded time inverval $[0,T]$. I'm much interested in the case where $b$ is divergence free, but informations about other cases are okay, too.

Comment: Actually... I think your question is already answered in DiPerna and Lion's paper (I assume you meant _ODE, transport theory, and Sobolev spaces_ in Inventione). Consider equation 11. Commute your transport equation with a derivative, you have $$ \partial_t (\partial u) + b\cdot \nabla (\partial u) + (\partial b)\cdot \nabla u = 0 $$ so $\partial u$ solves a system of the form equation 11. In general, commuting equation 11 with $\partial^k$ shows that the tower $(u, \partial u, \partial^2u, \ldots,\partial^ku)$ solves a transport equation also of form 11. 

Comment: So apply the result there to the tower being in $L^q$ gives you a result for $u$ in $W^{k,q}$, which also requires upgrading the Sobolev space assumption on $b$ and $c$ to contain more derivatives. 

Comment: @Wille Wong: Thanks for your answer. I think, this is the point for higher regularity. Thanks!

Do you (or others) know if there is a further development for this equation beyond the paper of DiPerna and Lions?

Answer (score 2):

You can start with an interesteing extension - Ambrosio 2004 showed existence, uniqueness and stability results for $b\in BV$ and ${\rm div}_x b$ absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure.